# Description: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

The following is the metadata of my source table:

```
Hours_StageTbl

type        varchar(100)
Op          varchar(100)
SN          varchar(100)
Hours       float
R_Date      varchar(100)
Source      int
BeginDate   date
Age         float
```

The following is the metadata of my destination table:

```
Hours

HoursId    PK, uniqueidentifier
SN         varchar(100)
Type       varchar(100)
Source     int
Date       datetime
Op         varchar(100)
Age        float
Hours      float
BornOnDate datetime
```

The following is my metadata for the table that I `JOIN` to:

```
A_Age

Type varchar(50)
SN varchar(50)
Op varchar(50)
Reg varchar(50)
RDateAge decimal
Date date
```

The following is my `SQL Command Text` in the `OLE DB Source Editor` in `SSIS`:

```
SELECT 
    F.Type
   ,F.Op
   ,F.SN
   ,F.Hours
   ,convert(date, F.R_Date +'28', 111) AS 'R_Date'
   ,F.Source
   ,F.BeginDate
   ,F.Age
   ,A.Type
   ,A.SN
   ,A.Op AS 'A_Op'
   ,A.Reg
   ,A.RDateAge
   ,A.Date
   ,(DATEDIFF(dd, convert(date, F.R_Date +'28', 111), GETDATE())/365.00) + A.RDateAge    as 'AdjustedAge'  
FROM 
    Hours_StageTbl F
INNER JOIN 
    A_Age A
    ON 
    F.SN = A.SN
ORDER BY 
    F.SN
   ,F.Date
```

My `OLE DB Source Editor` flows to `Data Conversion` and again converts `Date` from `Source` table to `DT_Date` which then flows to `OLE DB Command`.

It must be noted that `Date varchar(100)` From `Hours_StageTbl` (source table)  is to be inserted into `Date       datetime` in `Hours` (destination table) and is what is giving me problem I believe.

No matter what I do to try to fix the conversion I get the following error:

`An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E07  Description: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".`

I have spent hours trying to rectify this.  An extra set of eyes would be great.

Comment: Show the data in `F.R_Date` and `F.Date`

Comment: It most likely means this expression: `convert(date, F.R_Date +'28', 111)` fails because data in that field doesn't match the required format (111 is `YYYY/MM/DD`). However it could be due to a number of things. The first step to solving the problem is running selective parts of your query until you isolate the issue. For example, open up SSMS and run this: `SELECT convert(date, R_Date +'28', 111) FROM Hours_StageTbl` Do you still get the error? If so, inspect the data in that field and find the data that doesn't match the format.

Comment: Now that I look closely, you have specified the field `R_Date` in your description. Regardless, look through your data and find out which data does not match the format.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I see that. When I get back into work I will check that and repost.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That was an error on my part when I posted.  I still can't find the reason why I am getting this error.  Does the `convert()` not fully convert or something?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The problem was in my stored procedure.  The variable I declared for that particular column was set to `nvarchar`.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Issue on Convert(date, F.R_Date +'28', 111).

Don't add days directly with string. Use funcion DateAdd( Eg. DateAdd(dd,4,R_Date ) )

EG.

Convert(date, DateAdd(dd,28, F.R_Date ), 111)